# SUMIF Excel Formula c# Exception Unhandled

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm trying to use the SUMIF formula in Excel using C#. I'm using the following code:

```
   oRng = (bSheet.Cells[row, 2] as Excel.Range);
   oRng.Formula = "=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A;A1;Sheet1!B:B)";
```

This returns "Exception Unhandled" error. In this case, I tried use another formula as simple SUM(Sheet1!A1:A3) and it worked perfectly.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,A1,Sheet1!B:B)`.  The argument delimiter should be a comma, not a semicolon.